# docker-compose, rebuild image(s) without starting containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I docker compose, it is possible to define the context as follows

```
version: '3'
services:
    node1:
            build: node1
            image: node1
            container_name: node1

    node2:
            build: node2
            image: node2
            container_name: node2
```

Where build refers to directory containing Dockerfile and the build resources. By using the command `docker-compose up -d --build` it is possible to rebuild images and restart changed containers. But using the following docker-compose file, is it possible to only build images without starting them, and preferably choose the images to build or build all?

Answer (score 6):

You can also try `docker-compose up --no-start`
It will perform build , create network , create volume without starting containers.

```
Usage: up [options] [--scale SERVICE=NUM...] [SERVICE...]

Options:
    -d, --detach               Detached mode: Run containers in the background,
                               print new container names. Incompatible with
                               --abort-on-container-exit.
    --no-color                 Produce monochrome output.
    --quiet-pull               Pull without printing progress information
    --no-deps                  Don't start linked services.
    --force-recreate           Recreate containers even if their configuration
                               and image haven't changed.
    --always-recreate-deps     Recreate dependent containers.
                               Incompatible with --no-recreate.
    --no-recreate              If containers already exist, don't recreate
                               them. Incompatible with --force-recreate and -V.
    --no-build                 Don't build an image, even if it's missing.
    --no-start                 Don't start the services after creating them.
```

Answer (score 5):

You can build specific services without starting them like so:

`docker-compose build node1`

To build them all:

`docker-compose build`